# What kind of algorithm is needed to fit a GARCH model?

Tags: garch, optimization

For fitting a GARCH model, I maximize the sum of the loglikelihoods of the errors. In Excel I simply use Solver. But what algorithm/library should I use if I don't want to use Excel?

Comment: If you are asking for software, this is off topic. Or are you asking what kind of optimization algorithm (independent of software) works best for GARCH models (converges fastest, does not get stuck) ?

Comment: @RichardHardy I'm asking for the algorithms. For now, I'm thinking on implementing GRG, which is a nonlinear constrained optimizer

Comment: You could check the documentation and/or vignette of the "rugarch" package in R. I will see if I find something more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non linear optimization. For example: GRG, Cobyla, etc